# Flink time window based on event time output nothing

Tags: apache-flink

In a stream processing problem, we have 3 sensors that each generate a timestamped sample every 8 milliseconds (Sensor's times are synchronized). So I want to merge data for every timestamp (In case of 3 sensors we should output 3 merged sample data for every timestamp). In addition, we have a time limit of 160 milliseconds such that every data should be outputted at most after 160 milliseconds since it's generated timestamp. So I decided to use Flink EventTime concept and a time window. Because timestamp is unique in every sensor's sample, we consider it as key for datastream.

```
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
SingleOutputStreamOperator<Tuple3<String,Long, JSONObject>> res = aggregatedTuple
                .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor<Tuple3<String, Long, JSONObject>>(Time.milliseconds(160)) {

            @Override
            public long extractTimestamp(Tuple3<String, Long, JSONObject> element) {
                return element.f1 ;
            }
        }).keyBy(1).timeWindow(Time.milliseconds(160))
                .allowedLateness(Time.milliseconds(2))
                .sideOutputLateData(lateOutputTag)
                .reduce(Do merging samples);
```

In the code, we first introduce the second field of the stream as an event time and set a periodic watermark (since data are generated at a fixed rate with a fixed delay). After that, we set the event time as key for the stream. we want to gather late data, too so we used `sideOutputLateData`. At last, we reduce (merge) data with the same key. The problem is in the Flink event time mode the defined window doesn't output any data! Without setting event time it will output data but I want to use event time as a time for Flin windowing. I tried multiple time for window and watermark but they didn't output anything.

I solved the same problem using Flink count window and a customized timeout trigger successfully.

**Update:** The incoming datastream format is in the type (If we had 3 sensor):

```
sensor_id, timestamp, data
(1, 1531980773390, {})
(2, 1531980773390, {})
(3, 1531980773390, {})
(1, 1531980773398, {})
(2, 1531980773398, {})
(3, 1531980773398, {})
```

and so on for every 8 milliseconds.

**Saving late data in a datastream**

```
final OutputTag<Tuple3<String, Long, JSONObject>> lateOutputTag = new OutputTag<Tuple3<String, Long, JSONObject>>("late-data") {
        };
DataStream<Tuple3<String, Long, JSONObject>> lateData = res.getSideOutput(lateOutputTag);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be that everything is late?

By default, periodic watermark generators are called every 200msec (measured in real time, not event time). That may be rather long in your case. Use [setAutoWatermarkInterval](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/ExecutionConfig.html#setAutoWatermarkInterval-long-) to change this. You may also want to think about using [setBufferTimeout](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/datastream_api.html#controlling-latency) to reduce latency.

Comment: Thanks, I save late data in a datastream but there is no data in that datastream, too. I update the question and add the type of the incoming data stream and you can see how event time (the second field of data) actually is. Does this help to solve the problem?

Comment: I addition I thought the input argument of `BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor` will set the periodic watermark. Am I right? If yes so why we should set `setAutoWatermarkInterval`?

Comment: The extractor is used for setting value for the Watermark. The interval says how often a new Watermark (with value calculated by the extractor) should be generated.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you key by the timestamp.

You should have keyBy(0) so that you split the stream by sensor id.