# flink 1.12.2 all events getting dropped as late

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

My flink pipeline looks something like below

```
FlinkKafkaConsumerBase kafkaConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(topic, new DeserializationSchema(),props);

kafkaSource = env.addSource(kafkaConsumer).filter(<>);
WatermarkStrategy<GenericMetricV2> watermarkStrategy = WatermarkStrategy
                .<GenericMetricV2>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(900))
                .withTimestampAssigner((metric, timestamp) -> {
                    logger.info("ETS: mts: {}, ts: {}", metric.metricPoint.timeInstant, timestamp);
                    return metric.metricPoint.timeInstant;
                });

metricStream = kafkasource
                        .process(<>)
                        .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(watermarkStrategy)
                        .transform("debugFilter", TypeInformation.of(<>), new StreamWatermarkDebugFilter<>("Op"))
                        .filter(<>)
                        .map(<>)
                        .flatMap(<>)
                        .keyBy(<>)
                        .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(300)))
                        .allowedLateneess(Time.seconds(900))
                        .sideOutputLateData(lateOutputTag)
                        .aggregate(AggregateFunction, ProcessWindowFunction)
                        .addSink()
```

I am running with parallelism 1 and default `setAutowatermarkInterval` of 200 ms. I did not set `setStreamTimeCharacteristic` as from flink 1.12 by default it is event time.

I am seeing that watermark is progressing from the output of [StreamWatermarkDebugFilter](https://github.com/antonmry/flink-playground/blob/main/src/main/java/galiglobal/flink/eventTime/StreamWatermarkDebugFilter.java) but all the events are getting marked as late and is getting gathered at `lateOutputTag`.

```
2021-05-18 17:14:19,745 INFO                  - ETS: mts: 1621310100000, ts: 1621310582271
2021-05-18 17:14:19,745 INFO                  - ETS: mts: 1621310100000, ts: 1621310582271
2021-05-18 17:14:19,842 INFO  StreamWatermarkDebugFilter         - Op, Watermark: 1621309499999
2021-05-18 17:14:19,944 INFO                  - ETS: mts: 1621309800000, ts: 1621310582275
2021-05-18 17:14:19,944 INFO                  - ETS: mts: 1621309800000, ts: 1621310582275
...
2021-05-18 17:14:20,107 INFO                  - ETS: mts: 1621310380000, ts: 1621310582278
2021-05-18 17:14:20,107 INFO                  - ETS: mts: 1621310380000, ts: 1621310582278
2021-05-18 17:14:20,137 INFO  StreamWatermarkDebugFilter         - Op, Watermark: 1621309779999
2021-05-18 17:14:20,203 INFO                  - ETS: mts: 1621309800000, ts: 1621310582279
...
2021-05-18 17:17:47,839 INFO                  - ETS: mts: 1621310100000, ts: 1621310681159
2021-05-18 17:17:47,848 INFO  StreamWatermarkDebugFilter         - Op, Watermark: 1621310099999
2021-05-18 17:17:47,958 INFO                  - ETS: mts: 1621309800000, ts: 1621310681237
2021-05-18 17:17:47,958 INFO                  - ETS: mts: 1621309800000, ts: 1621310681237
...
2021-05-18 17:22:24,207 INFO                  - ETS: mts: 1621310100000, ts: 1621310703622
2021-05-18 17:22:24,229 INFO  StreamWatermarkDebugFilter         - Op, Watermark: 1621310399999
2021-05-18 17:22:24,315 INFO                  - ETS: mts: 1621309800000, ts: 1621310705177
2021-05-18 17:22:24,315 INFO                  - ETS: mts: 1621309800000, ts: 1621310705177
```

I have seen this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61020086/flink-window-function-getresult-not-fired) and it is not an idleness problem.

It looks like related to this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51399973/flink-time-window-based-on-event-time-output-nothing). Can someone suggest how can I debug this problem further to identify what could be the problem?

Comment: For every event to be late, I'm thinking there must be something curious going on in the parts of the pipeline you haven't shared. To debug this, I would move the debugFilter to be immediately before the window, and have it print out the timestamps of all events and watermarks.

Comment: I will do it. One query since I am adding the watermark strategy not at the Kafka source but after `kafkasource -> process` . What is the initial watermark before `process` is getting invoked? Will it be the kafka record timestamp? If yes can I disable the watermark generation at kafka source as I am reading historical data from kafka?

Comment: It's generally prefered to apply your watermark strategy in the kafka source; it's not clear why you want to avoid that (it doesn't matter that it is historic data). As you have it now there are no watermarks in the early part of the pipeline (before the watermark generator), and flink's StreamRecord timestamps are initially the kafka header timestamps, which are then being overwritten by your timestamp assigner. The timestamps provided by kafka are the timestamps being printed in your timestamp assigner.

Comment: Yes it is not due to historic data. I could not put the watermark strategy right at the kafka source as I need to filter some data and then do some processing in `process()` to get the data in the desired format before I can put the strategy.

Comment: BTW, I'm not sure what the units are for allowedLateness, but it is probably msec -- in which case, 900 msec of allowedLateness is very small compared to the other intervals.

Comment: It was a problem on the part of code I did not share. I was doing a `filter()` after `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks` so the skewed data which I was not interested were pushing the watermark forward. I moved the `filter()` before `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks` and it is working as expected. Thanks for suggesting to move the debugFilter before window which helped to identify this.

Comment: I fixed the allowedLateness(900) in my question. It was a typo on posting the question.

Comment: Thanks for sharing what you discovered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem on the part of code I did not share. I was doing a `filter()` after `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks()` so the skewed data which I was not interested in were pushing the watermark forward. I moved the `filter()` before `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks` and it is working as expected.